# Use TinyMce with bundling get ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tinymce

I have a TypeScript Nextjs project, and I want to use TinyMce without API key.

I take a reference from official
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-pm-bundle/

And then I create a BundledEditor.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react'

// TinyMCE so the global var exists
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce'

// DOM model
import 'tinymce/models/dom/model'

// Theme
import 'tinymce/themes/silver'

// Toolbar icons
import 'tinymce/icons/default'

// Editor styles
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css'

// importing the plugin js.
// if you use a plugin that is not listed here the editor will fail to load
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist'
import 'tinymce/plugins/anchor'
import 'tinymce/plugins/autolink'
import 'tinymce/plugins/autoresize'
import 'tinymce/plugins/autosave'
import 'tinymce/plugins/charmap'
import 'tinymce/plugins/code'
import 'tinymce/plugins/codesample'
import 'tinymce/plugins/directionality'
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons'
import 'tinymce/plugins/fullscreen'
import 'tinymce/plugins/help'
import 'tinymce/plugins/image'
import 'tinymce/plugins/importcss'
import 'tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime'
import 'tinymce/plugins/link'
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists'
import 'tinymce/plugins/media'
import 'tinymce/plugins/nonbreaking'
import 'tinymce/plugins/pagebreak'
import 'tinymce/plugins/preview'
import 'tinymce/plugins/quickbars'
import 'tinymce/plugins/save'
import 'tinymce/plugins/searchreplace'
import 'tinymce/plugins/table'
import 'tinymce/plugins/template'
import 'tinymce/plugins/visualblocks'
import 'tinymce/plugins/visualchars'
import 'tinymce/plugins/wordcount'

// importing plugin resources
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons/js/emojis'

// Content styles, including inline UI like fake cursors
/* eslint import/no-webpack-loader-syntax: off */
import contentCss from '!!raw-loader!tinymce/skins/content/default/content.min.css'
import contentUiCss from '!!raw-loader!tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css'

export default function BundledEditor(props) {
  const { init, ...rest } = props

  // note that skin and content_css is disabled to avoid the normal
  // loading process and is instead loaded as a string via content_style
  return (
    <Editor
      init={{
        ...init,
        skin: false,
        content_css: false,
        content_style: [contentCss, contentUiCss, init.content_style || ''].join('\n')
      }}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}
```

And use it on the other tsx file.

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import BundledEditor from '../BundledEditor'

const editorRef = useRef<any>(null)

return (
  <>
                        <BundledEditor
                      onInit={(evt: any, editor: any) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
                      initialValue=''
                      init={{
                        height: 500,
                        menubar: false,
                        plugins: [
                          'advlist',
                          'anchor',
                          'autolink',
                          'help',
                          'image',
                          'link',
                          'lists',
                          'searchreplace',
                          'table',
                          'wordcount'
                        ],
                        toolbar:
                          'undo redo | blocks | ' +
                          'bold italic forecolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
                          'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
                          'removeformat | help',
                        content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
                      }}
                    />
  </>
);
```

Every thing is fine, but when I just refresh the page, it will show error `ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`

I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try importing the package like below:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const Editor = dynamic(
    () => import("@tinymce/tinymce-react"),
    { ssr: false }
);
```

Comment: You save me a day ! Now I get the point, `ssr` will cause the issue. Thanks